# The anti-symmetrization and simetrization operators are mutually orthogonal

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces, permutations, operator-theory, group-actions

For each vector $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, and for each permutation $s$ of the symmetric group on the $n$-element set $S_n$, put $s(x)=(x_{s(1)},\dots,x_{s(n)})$. Then the anti-symmetrization and symmetrization operators defined bellow are mutually orthogonal.

$$A={1 \over n!}\sum_{s\in S_n}\text{sgn}(s)s$$
$$S={1 \over n!}\sum_{s\in S_n}s$$
Here "sgn" is the parity function.

I could not justify the following equation:

$$\sum_{s\in S_n}\sum_{p\in S_n}\text{sgn}(p)sp=\sum_{t\in S_n}t\sum_{p\in S_n}\text{sgn}(p)$$

Apparently $t=sp$ but why can we take $t$ out of the sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** for clarity, I'm using parentheses and $\cdot$ to denote multiplication by scalars.

First, note 
$$\sum_{s\in S_n}\left(\sum_{p\in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(p)\cdot sp\right) = \sum_{p\in S_n}\left(\mathrm{sgn}(p)\cdot\sum_{s\in S_n}sp\right).$$
Second, for a given $p\in S_n$ and every $t\in S_p$ there exists $s\in S_n$ such that $sp=t$ (namely, $s=tp^{-1}$), and vice versa. Therefore
$$\sum_{s\in S_n}sp = \sum_{t\in S_n}t$$

However, writing the last equality the other way around, i.e.,
$$\sum_{p\in S_n}\left(\mathrm{sgn}(p)\cdot\sum_{t\in S_n}t\right) =
\sum_{t\in S_n}\left(t\sum_{p\in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(p)\right),$$
might be confusing, as $\sum_{p\in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(p)$ is simply the zero scalar (with the field addition), whereas all other sums are additions in $V$. It might be better to denote
$$\sum_{p\in S_n}\left(\mathrm{sgn}(p)\cdot\sum_{t\in S_n}t\right) =
\left(\sum_{p\in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(p)\right)\cdot\sum_{t\in S_n}t = 0\cdot\sum_{t\in S_n}t = \underline{0}$$

Comment: Could you please put brackets even where they are not necessary. For instance even when it is clear by the summation indexes that you do not mean product of sums. Moreover, my equation is just, because both $$\sum_{p\in S_n}(\mathrm{sgn}(p)\sum_{t\in S_n}t)$$ and $$\sum_{t\in S_n}(t\sum_{p\in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(p))$$ are zero, but one should never have to arrive at the latter for apparently the first one is enough to prove the claim, isn't that so?

Comment: @Student, it's customary to multiply operators (or elements of any algebra) by scalars from the left, which is why I don't appreciate the latter as much. I guess one would have to distribute that way to realize the result is zero, though.